# What is Mii Fujibakama saying?

Tags: japanese-language, date-a-live

I would like to know what Mii Fujibakama is saying in romaji in the anime is "Date to a Live". At minute 15:15 of episode 1 of season 2 she says something like " Majikku " but it isn't that!! I been searching everywhere on Google for hours how to type/write that in romaji? I know the meaning in English which means gross or disgusting, but I couldn't find how to write it in romaji.

It's the girl wearing glasses that has purple hair. How do you write what she says?

Comment: Please don't link to unlicensed streaming sites. As for your question itself, I'm pretty sure she always says the same thing, まじひくわー, which in romaji would be written *majihikuwaa*.

Answer (score 5):

I'm promoting my comment above to an answer. What she says in every instance she talks is 「まじひくわー」, or *majihikuwaa*.

Here, *maji* (まじ) means "really" or "seriously". It's a very strong, almost superlative way of modifying whatever follows, so it's literal meaning might be closer to "profoundly" or "incredibly", but it's far more colloquial than those.

*Hiku* (引く) is a common verb which has several possible meanings. The meaning here is a rather colloquial one, which literally means something like "to reel back in disgust or fear". The use of the verb in an unconjugated form here is rather casual, and would not be done in polite speech.

The sentence ends with *waa* (わー). *wa* is a feminine way to end a sentence (see [this question on Japanese SE](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2886/when-women-use-%E3%82%8F-at-the-end-of-a-sentence-is-it-different-from-%E3%82%88)). It's relatively uncommon in real life. It doesn't add much meaning here. Making the vowel long at the end just emphasizes the statement while making it less polite.

So in all, 「まじひくわー」 is a slang phrase which means something to the effect of "That's seriously gross". I'm simplifying things a bit here as the meaning could change a bit depending on context, how it's pronounced, etc., but it's always going to be a rather strong, course slang expression of disgust.